# Better way to recalculate pandas dataframe fields depending on other fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am new to python pandas.
And i wanted to estimate a value of inflow payment/s over term considering fees and growth over a period.
I only used one payment (inflow) to test.
Sometimes fee2 can be applied up to period n-t. i.e. Not for the whole period, n.

I did it like below, just wondering if there is a better way to recalculate the values without looping?

Example in spreadsheet:
[image]

Python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def getCashFlows():
   term = 2
   growthRate = (1+0.06)**(1/12) - 1
   df = pd.DataFrame(list(range(1,term*12+1)), columns=['t'])
   df['Value_t_1'] = 0
   df['Inflow1']=0
   df['growth']=0
   df['ValuePlusGrowth'] = 0
   df['fee1']=0
   df['fee2']=30
   df['Value_t']=0

   df.set_value(0, 'Inflow1', 10000)

   for i in range(0,term*12):
      df['Value_t_1'] = df['Value_t'].shift()
      df['Value_t_1'].fillna(0,inplace=True)

      df['growth'] = (df['Value_t_1'] + df['Inflow1'])*growthRate
      df['ValuePlusGrowth'] = df['Value_t_1']+df['Inflow1']+df['growth']
      df['fee1']=df['ValuePlusGrowth']*0.5/100
      df['Value_t'] = df['ValuePlusGrowth'] - df['fee1'] - df['fee2']
   return df
```

Comment: just get rid of the def & for and run the rest of the code.  the looping is implicit.  you have "for i" but no "i" so all you're doing is repeating the exact same code 24 times instead of once, and it runs on the entire df every time

Comment: @JohnE - actually not quite. Initially I thought the same but notice the `shift()` in first line. Each loop looks forward on *Value_t*. And in doing so OP is actually accumulating these values across 24 periods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only initial input that's really needed is the initial value for `inflow`.  Everything else can be reduced to operations that are repeated for a set number of times, based on the row index.  And some of the columns in your data frame are really just constants.

Here's a solution that clarifies the operations needed to compute each row of the data frame:

```
import pandas as pd

class GrowthTracker(object):

    def __init__(self, n_iter):

        self.colnames = ['Value_t_1', 'growth', 'ValuePlusGrowth', 'fee1', 'Value_t']
        self.data = None
        self.fee1_mult = 0.5/100
        self.fee2 = (0,0,0,0,30)
        self.growthRate = (1+0.06)**(1/12) - 1
        self.n_iter = n_iter
        self.ops = pd.Series([1, # Value_t_1
                              self.growthRate, # growth
                              (1 + self.growthRate), # ValuePlusGrowth
                              (1 + self.growthRate) * self.fee1_mult, # fee1
                              (1 + self.growthRate) * (1 - self.fee1_mult) # Value_t
                             ])

    def update(self, t, n, df=None):
        row = self.ops.mul(t).subtract(self.fee2)
        tmp = pd.concat([df, row], axis = 1, ignore_index=True)
        if n < self.n_iter: 
            self.data = self.update(row.iloc[-1], n+1, tmp)
            return self.data
        else:
            tmp.iloc[0,0] = 0 # remove the initial 10000 from Value_t_1
            self.data = tmp.T
            self.data.columns = self.colnames
            return self.data
```

Now just set the initial values, instantiate the `GrowthTracker` object, and `update()`:

```
total_iter = 23

tracker = GrowthTracker(n_iter=total_iter)

inflow = 10000
start_index = 0

tracker.update(t=inflow, n=start_index)

tracker.data

      Value_t_1     growth  ValuePlusGrowth       fee1      Value_t
0      0.000000  48.675506     10048.675506  50.243378  9968.432128
1   9968.432128  48.521847     10016.953976  50.084770  9936.869206
2   9936.869206  48.368213      9985.237419  49.926187  9905.311232
3   9905.311232  48.214603      9953.525835  49.767629  9873.758206
4   9873.758206  48.061017      9921.819223  49.609096  9842.210127
5   9842.210127  47.907455      9890.117583  49.450588  9810.666995
6   9810.666995  47.753918      9858.420912  49.292105  9779.128808
7   9779.128808  47.600404      9826.729212  49.133646  9747.595566
8   9747.595566  47.446914      9795.042480  48.975212  9716.067268
9   9716.067268  47.293449      9763.360716  48.816804  9684.543913
10  9684.543913  47.140007      9731.683920  48.658420  9653.025500
11  9653.025500  46.986590      9700.012090  48.500060  9621.512030
12  9621.512030  46.833196      9668.345226  48.341726  9590.003500
13  9590.003500  46.679827      9636.683327  48.183417  9558.499910
14  9558.499910  46.526482      9605.026392  48.025132  9527.001260
15  9527.001260  46.373160      9573.374420  47.866872  9495.507548
16  9495.507548  46.219863      9541.727411  47.708637  9464.018774
17  9464.018774  46.066590      9510.085364  47.550427  9432.534937
18  9432.534937  45.913341      9478.448278  47.392241  9401.056037
19  9401.056037  45.760116      9446.816152  47.234081  9369.582072
20  9369.582072  45.606915      9415.188986  47.075945  9338.113041
21  9338.113041  45.453737      9383.566779  46.917834  9306.648945
22  9306.648945  45.300584      9351.949529  46.759748  9275.189781
23  9275.189781  45.147455      9320.337237  46.601686  9243.735551
```

I found it easier to express this all as a class, but it's simple enough to just define variables outside of the class and then just run the `update()` function.

**UPDATE**
Here's a bit more explanation behind this solution:

The initial data frame `df` is mostly empty.  The only fully non-zero columns are `t`, which is never used, and `fee2`, which is a constant (`fee2 = 30`).  The entire remainder of `df` starts out as zero-valued, with the one exception of the first cell in `Inflow1` - its first value is `10000`, and the rest of its values are zeros.

That means that, in terms of what we need to accomplish computationally, we can limit our "matrix of interest" to the columns `Value_t_1`, `growth`, `ValuePlusGrowth`, `fee1`, and `Value_t`.

We can think of that first `Inflow1` value as the seed - everything else is just a string of operations performed on the number `10000`. (In fact, we don't actually need `Inflow1` as a field, as all of its other values remain zero throughout the calculations.)

In your loop, you initially updated columns using the values of other columns.  That makes sense, it's probably how I would have done it too - looks neat and efficient.  Recall, however, that every update is really just a string of math tracing its lineage back to that original `10000`. Writing out the actual operations for each column update, instead of using other column names, shows how each update operation can be simplified.

First, a few shorthand notations:

```
t = Value_t from previous row (in case of the first row, Value_t = Inflow1 = 10000)
t1 = Value_t_1 
g = growth
inf = Inflow1 
vpg = ValuePlusGrowth
gr = growthRate # gr is a constant: (1+0.06)**(1/12) - 1
f1X = 0.5/100
new_t = Value_t for current row
```

We start with `t = 10000`. Everything else is some operation on `t`.

Every value can be expressed in terms of what we need to multiply `t` by in order to get the desired value (with one exception that I'll get to later).  So for example:

```
df['Value_t_1'] = df['Value_t'].shift()
df['Value_t_1'].fillna(0,inplace=True)

# equivalent to:
t1 = 1 * t # recall t is the shifted Value_t from the previous row
```

Keep in mind that we only need to drop in the seed value `t` once, and then it's just operations on the seed to populate all of `df`.  That means that the operations in your loop can be expressed as "the terms that need to be multiplied by t in order to get the correct column value".  So although we have shown that `t1 = 1 * t`, it's more useful for us to think of `t1 = 1` - eventually we'll multiply that by `t`, but the right side of that equation represents `t1`'s relationship to `t`.

Then:

```
t1 = 1
```

Next:

```
# Inflow1 is always 0, except for its initial value which we capture in initial t, so:
df['growth'] = (df['Value_t_1'] + df['Inflow1'])*growthRate
# becomes:
g = t1 * gr 
# with t1 = 1
g = gr

# we know t1 = 1, and inf is never used as a multiplier, so:
df['ValuePlusGrowth'] = df['Value_t_1']+df['Inflow1']+df['growth']
# becomes:
vpg = 1 + g = 1 + gr

df['fee1']=df['ValuePlusGrowth']*0.5/100
# becomes:
fee1 = vpg * f1X = (1 + gr) * f1X

# we'll ignore subtracting fee2 for now, see notes below.
df['Value_t'] = df['ValuePlusGrowth'] - df['fee1'] - df['fee2']
# becomes:
new_t = vpg - fee1 = (1 + gr) - ((1 + gr) * f1X) = (1 + gr) * (1 - f1X)

ops = (t1, g, vpg, fee1, new_t)
```

Now, for each row, we have a set of update operations `ops` for each column. Given that we have `t` from the previous row, we can populate values for each row with:

```
new_row = t * ops
```

We still need to subtract `fee2` from `new_t`, and that doesn't fit neatly into what, up until this point, had been a series of multiplicative operations.  But we can stick with our vectorized formulation and define:

```
fee2 = (0,0,0,0,30)
```

After each `new_row` we subtract the `fee2` vector from the `new_row` vector, which really just subtracts `fee2` from `new_t` as desired.

```
new_row = t * ops - fee2
```

At this point, we just need a function that starts with `t = 10000` and keeps executing the `new_row` formula, building on each previous row, until we've reached our desired number of iterations.  I chose a recursive strategy to do this, and saved each `new_row` to a data frame at every recursive step.

Finally, since I somewhat abused your original notation by setting `t = 10000` instead of `Inflow1 = 10000`, this means the first `t1` value is incorrectly set at `10000`. At the end of the `update()` function we set this first `t1` value back to `0`.

Comment: thanks @andrew_reece, but am struggling to run the code, i fixed other simple errors like missing self before referencing some variables...but the recursion call to update(self, t, n, df=None),  update(row.iloc[-1], n+1, self.n_iter, tmp), has an extra value (row.iloc[-1]) i cant match

Comment: Sorry about that, I had some variables hanging around in my environment before I converted to a class-based approach, and I didn't clear everything to test before I posted.  My fault.  Updated now, and I've started this code from a fresh kernel and confirmed that everything is working as posted.

Comment: Thanks a lot...took longer cause i wanted to make sure i understand it...

Comment: You're welcome, I really enjoyed this challenge.  I added some explanation to clarify my implementation, see updated solution.